# Photos from Facebook SDK

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook-graph-api

I have been trying to get all the photos from facebook...i referred the code from graph api

```
        NSMutableDictionary* parameters = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
        [parameters setValue:@"id,name,photos" forKey:@"fields"];
            [[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"me" parameters:parameters]
             startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error){
                 NSLog(@"RESULT===%@",result);

             }];
```

but the log in result not showing any photos....kindly help

Comment: And the `error` is nil?

Comment: have you taken permission from Facebook for get photos from user's profile?

Comment: yes i have took permisions for user_photos

Answer (score 0):

Here first you have to get Album id by

```
FBSDKGraphRequest *request=[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"me/albums" parameters:nil];
[request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {

    }else {
        NSLog(@"error %@", error.description);

    }
}];
```

Then get photos of particular album

```
FBSDKGraphRequest *request=[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"AlbumId/photos" parameters:nil HTTPMethod:@"GET"];

[request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result1, NSError *error) {

    if(!error)
    {

    }else{

    }
}];
```